# YouTube Analytics API: Get subscribers gained/lost by traffic source for video

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

Using the YouTube Analytics API, is it possible to retrieve the number of subscribers gained and lost by traffic source grouped or filtered by video?

The YouTube Analytics application has a "Subscribers Report" https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714347?hl=en where it displays this data for all videos. I would like to retrieve this information with the YouTube Analytics API for each video.